# SQLiteException: near "Ange": syntax error (code 1):

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I wrote a method in DatabaseHelper class as below, it works for short lists but does not for long lists,
I get the error `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Ange": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT genre FROM second WHERE name='L'Ange-Gardien and Notre-Dame de la Salette Police, Fire and EMS'` I remove the item L'Ange-Gardien and Notre-Dame de la Salette Police, Fire and EMS but it still gives error.

```
    public String getScannerTypeByRadioName(String radioName) {
    String scannerType = null;
    myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT genre FROM second WHERE name='" + radioName + "'";
    Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        scannerType = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("genre"));
    }
    return scannerType;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't ever use concatenation of parameters that you want to pass in an sql statement.
In this line:

```
String query = "SELECT genre FROM second WHERE name='" + radioName + "'";
```

you concatenate the string `radioName` with value:

```
L'Ange-Gardien and Notre-Dame de la Salette Police, Fire and EMS
```

which contains a single quote and this creates an invalid sql statement.
Use the recommended way with `?` placeholders:

```
String query = "SELECT genre FROM second WHERE name=?";
Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(query, new String[] {radioName});
```

Comment: I get now one more error whick is
CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=1325 (# cursors opened by this proc=1325)
starts by "while (c.moveToNext()) ...."
can you help me forpas?

Comment: This error is often thrown because you use cursors and not close them at the end. So use always cursor.close() after you are done with a cursor. In this code, just before `return scannerType;` write `c.close()`. But you have to do the same always.

Comment: Hi again, when I change the device language I get the error, 
IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null,
in line;
String query = "SELECT genre FROM second WHERE name='" + radioName + "'";
do you have any offer :)  Thank you very much forpas

Comment: (1) Don't use this form of the sql statement. Use the form with the ? placeholder. (2) before you execute rawQuery() check if the parameter radioName is null and if it is don't execute it.

Comment: actually I used the form with ? but I don't know how should check radioname is empty or not, could you look at page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60964966/when-i-changed-the-device-language-app-crashes ? there is my exact new code. forpas

Comment: After this line: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();` add `if (string == null) {return list};` so the method returns and does not execute the query.