# When I changed the device language, app crashes

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I used SQLite and in my project it works well if the device language is in English. However if I change the device language I get an error which is;

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null

....

com.radioapps.radiostations2020.models.DatabaseHelper.getRadioNamesByCountryName(DatabaseHelper.java:127)
```

line 127 is;

```
   Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(query, new String[]{string});
```

and the whole method is;

```
public List<String> getRadioNamesByCountryName(String string) {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT name FROM second WHERE country=?";
    Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery(query, new String[]{string});
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        list.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
    }
    c.close();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: check `string` is empty or null

Comment: it is not null, I checked it and moreover it works well in English so  it cannot be null IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: If its not null, is it some special character or something ?

Comment: yes, I found the problem, string comes null when I changed the language because of other codes related with navigation component args. I was sending countryName and it was changing by language. Fortunately I solved it, thank you IntelliJ Amiya and vizsatiz